# "samples x=0" options yields error with addplot3

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

I am trying to plot the riemann surface of ln(z), and I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
    domain=-10:10,
    y domain=-10:10]
    \addplot3[surf, samples=50] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi};
    \addplot3[surf, samples=50] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi+2*pi};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this produces an image similar to:

[image: this]

which has a jump which I would like to eliminate.

I tried writing

```
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
   domain=-10:10,
   y domain=-10:10]
   \addplot3[surf, samples=50, samples y=0] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi};
   \addplot3[surf, samples=50, samples y=0] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi+2*pi};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the compiler returns an error,

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex
>   pected to sample a line, not a mesh.

How to fix this problem? What is happening?

Comment: Where did you get `samples x` from? There is `samples` and `samples y`, if you don't set the latter the value of the former is used there as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`samples y` sets the number of y-values in the domain for which a data point is calculated. So it doesn't make sense to set it to zero, then you won't get any points at all.

I'm guessing you want the output below, what I did here is to split each surface in two, one for y<0, one for y>0. Whether this is the best approach I don't know.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
    domain=-10:10,
    ]
    \addplot3[surf, samples=25,y domain=-10:-0.001] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi};
    \addplot3[surf, samples=25,y domain=0.001:10]   {atan2(y,x)/180*pi};

    \addplot3[surf, samples=25,y domain=-10:-0.001] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi+2*pi};
    \addplot3[surf, samples=25,y domain=0.001:10] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi+2*pi};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```